# Network programming inside the View Controller... bad practice?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, theory, system-design

Quite a broad quesiton, I know.

Is it bad practice to keep networking in the View Controller, outside of the model? Or would this be preferred in the model? E.g. currently have a ViewController where I fetch JSON data via. a URL request, parse it, and present it to the view.

I use the data of the JSON result as attributes in an object of my data model. Bad practice?

I'm specifically working with iOS right now, but anything is okay for me, I'm just trying to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Assume your model means data object, I think the network code should be separated from both ViewController and Model,if possible, i.e.:enclose it in an individual class,NetworkHelper , and let the ViewController to operate  NetworkHelper to fill the model (data object).

It allows the network code to be tested individually. Also you can replace the data source easily (e.g.: use hardcode data instead of downloading) by replacing NetworkHelper.

It is the dependency relationship that may look like:

```
NetworkHelper--UIViewController
            \   /   |
            Model  UIView
```

Comment: Thanks, really interesting. I haven't thought of that. I guess it's okay to break out of the pattern if it has value for the project.